# What is the advantage of using Postgres with Esri architecture?

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-server

One of my tasks is to transfer shapefiles and .gdb data into a PostgreSQL database - not a problem. However, the database is to be connected to ArcGIS Server so that the data can be used by an ArcGIS Online app. This requires the creation of a geodatabase within the PostgreSQL database so that ArcGIS can connect to it.

This seems inefficient: The workflow, as communicated to me, is to receive data (probably as a shapefile) > Insert into PostgreSQL > Use geodatabase within PostgreSQL to provide data to ArcGIS Server.

The only advantage I can think of is that using PostgreSQL is a way to allow for easier access by other software. However, if this database is going to be used by Esri architecture, why not use a geodatabase?

Comment: Your premise is flawed. It is *not* necessary that an Enterprise geodatabase be registered in a PostgreSQL database for ArcGIS Server to access that database (this has been true since Query Layers were released).  The database connection credentials must be registered in the Server, but the database need not be Enterprise-enabled (versioning would of course be unavailable in the non-enabled database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database is only going to be used by the Esri Architecture than it doesn't make much sense but using a database as the backend (Postgres or any other) has significant advantages.  Geographic data stored in an RDBMS can be secured, backed up, queried and updated by non gis users.  The layers are stored as just another table.

I store data in SQL Server (using spatial geometry fields) and build mapservices off of these native sql tables.  Less of the ESRI overhead this way and as you said it allows access by all the other software available.  Data from ETL processes are input into the database and the services are updated without having to add features to a file geodatabase or creating new datasources like shapefiles.  RDBMS, whichever you choose is the best backend for a modern GIS system.

Comment: I think this is the right answer - the client may want to use this data for other things besides AGOL. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What did you call a geodatabase and witch one would you rather use? Postgres with either PostGIS extension or ESRI enterprise IS a geodatabase. The other alternative in the ESRI ecosystem are :

**File geodatabases** : can be stored on both Microsoft Windows and Linux platforms, but you should avoid using shared directories for storage

**Personal geodatabases** : store datasets in a Microsoft Access (.mdb) file on disk. The storage sizes of personal geodatabases are effectively limited to between 250 and 500 MB for the entire geodatabase and are only supported on Windows operating systems

**Desktop and workgroup geodatabases** :

- Desktop geodatabases allow only one editor at a time, but they can
  support up to three read-only connections, you cannot publish web
  services.
- Workgroup geodatabases allow multiple editors and read-only connections per geodatabase. You can also publish data to a workgroup-level ArcGIS Server site running on the same machine as the database server.

So if you have to stay in the ESRI ecosystem (for exemple to directly publish MXD on ArcGIS server or using Arcgis online apps), the only way to get data to Arcgis server is to use an enterprise geodatabase that has to be installed on either IBM Db2, IBM Informix, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle or PostgreSQL so you have in fact not much choice...

[Full description of the ESRI geodatabase type](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/a-comparison-of-geodatabase-types.htm)

(Of course deciding if using only ESRI product is the best way or not is another debate)

Comment: Good call, I should have specified "file geodatabase" - I was using the term to refer to esri-specific stuff.

Comment: Its possible to publish data using sql server geometry format direct from a RDBMS without having SDE or an ESRI specific Enterprise system.  There are a few issues you have to work through but I'm doing it.